# Print all data related to a certain field

Tags: text-processing, awk

Considering below file:

```
foo,5
foo,7
foo,9
boo,5
boo,10
boo,10
```

What I am looking to, is printing all the data in `$2` that is related to `$1` in one record.

For this example the needed output will be:

```
foo,5,7,9
boo,5,10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `awk` solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}!(($1,$2)in c){c[$1,$2]=1;r[$1]=r[$1] OFS $2}
            END{for(i in r){print i r[i]}}' file
```

1. Set `OFS=FS` for consistency.
2. Use `awk`'s [multidimensional array](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html#Multidimensional) to remember the `$2` values encountered so far. Only 'proceed' if there is no match (`!(($1,$2)in c)`).
3. Provide a 'dummy' value for the multidimensional array on first encounter of a new key.
4. Concatenate the desired output string into another array for convenience.
5. At the `END`, print the loop.

   - Note that the loop iteration is not in any particular order, you can use `awk`'s sorting features if required.

Answer (score 3):

Parse the data into "hashes" or "associative arrays" or "dictionaries" or whatever they are called:

```
perl -F, -lane '$first{$F[0]}->{$F[1]} = (); END { print join(",", $_, sort { $a <=> $b } keys %{ $first{$_} } ) for keys %first }' < inputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

A Solution in bash without awk:

```
$ cat bla.txt 
foo,5
foo,7
foo,9
boo,5
boo,10
boo,10

$ { buffer="";
  while read i ; do
    key="${i%,*}" ;
    if [[ "$key" == "$oldkey" ]] ; then
      idx="${i#*,}";
      if [[ ! "$idx" == "$oidx" ]] ; then
        buffer+=",$idx" ;
        oidx="$idx";
      fi ;
    else
      test -z $buffer || echo $buffer ;
      oldkey="$key" ;
      buffer="$i" ;
      oidx="${i#*,}" ;
    fi ;
  done ; echo $buffer ; } < bla.txt
foo,5,7,9
boo,5,10
$
```

It's not pretty or short, but it works. I would also be interested to see a solution with awk.

Comment: Careful with `read`.  It still strips backslashes in what it reads.  Besides being super slow because it has to read one character at a time.  pure-bash is nice for manipulating the text of one variable, but usually not a good choice for whole files.

Comment: True, @PeterCordes , has to kept in mind. OP did not indicate possible wierd or very_large input. My alternate answer using 'q' does not strip BackSlashes.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the [q - Text as database](https://github.com/harelba/q) tool. Its a single file Python script. Using it you can do:

```
$ cat bla.txt 
foo,5
foo,7
foo,9
boo,5
boo,10
boo,10

$ qry="select c1, group_concat(c2) from bla.txt group by c1" ;
$ q -d, "$qry" | sed -r 's/(,[^,]*)\1/\1/g'
boo,5,10
foo,5,7,9
```

This assumes the input file to be sorted. The trailing sed is only necessary to remove the duplicates in your input. If you don't have any, omit the sed. If you need a specific output order, you could add an "ORDER BY" Clause.

Answer (score 2):

With `gnu` [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
datamash -t ',' -s -g 1 unique 2 <infile
```

the order of the values in the output will be different though as they are sorted before being processed:

```
boo,10,5
foo,5,7,9
```

Answer (score 1):

using a combination of `cut`, `grep`, and `sort`, with a little formatting help by `sed` and `tr`. Also your output file will be sorted in both keywords and values for each keyword:

```
#get sorted, unique keyword list
cut -d, -f 1 file | sort -u |\
while read keyword ; do
  #echo keyword and sorted, unique occurrences of values
  #for keyword as output
  echo $keyword,$(grep "^$keyword," file | cut -d, -f2 |\
              sort -u | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//' )  \
  >> sorted_file
done
```

the one-liner:

```
cut -d, -f 1 file | sort -u | while read keyword ; do echo $keyword,$(grep "^$keyword," file | cut -d, -f2 | sort -u | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//' )  >> sorted_file ; done
```

Comment: Interesting, but you should grep for `"^$keyword,"` to avoid false-positive matches of other keys, or of data.  Also, this runs a whole pipeline for every unique keyword in the file, so it's not nearly as efficient as the one-pass awk solutions.

Comment: The `>> sorted_file` could be after the `done` of the outer loop, to only open the output file once.

Comment: Good point with the exact keyword match. Whether `>> sorted_file` is better after the loop is a matter of the size of the output, I guess, but yes, a single opening is faster. It is a pity that you need the `while` loop, as `grep` otherwise is pretty fast in comparison to `awk` when it comes to finding patterns.

Comment: Just noticed you don't quote `"$keyword"` or the command substitution output on the cmdline of `echo`, either.  It already can't contain spaces, but glob expansion happens after parameter expansion, so `keyword='foo*'` will do match that pattern against the directory contents.  If `"$keyword"` start with a `-`, `echo` will interpret it as options.  `printf '%s\n' "$keyword,$(...)"` is fully safe here.  Also, the `grep | cut` could be a single `sed`, but the way you wrote it is more readable and probably took less time to verify while writing.

Comment: you are right, the keyword could be anything and `printf` is saver. About using `sed` I am not too sure, as `grep` is much faster than `sed` ( AFAIK ) and the `cut` on the reduced output should not be an issue speed-wise.